# Is IPv6 Routing Header useless?

Tags: ipv6

[RFC2460](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460) doesn't describe any types other than Type 0. And in [RFC5095](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5095), it deprecated Type 0 Routing Header. Does that mean Routing Header is useless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, at this point in time, yes. The door is still open for future types, but I think the whole idea of the routing header was flawed to begin with. Add the fact that some variants of SDN want to do something similar, and I think the idea is dead.

I have never thought it a good idea to let end-devices try to dictate the path packets take through the network. Similarly, if you look at QoS, most successful QoS implementations usually overwrite the end-device supplied DSCP value in order to create a comprehensive, consistent QoS solution; everybody wants their traffic marked `EF`.

Comment: Yes, it the IPv6 version of "source route", which was a defunct (no one allowed it) option when v6 was designed. (yet more head-in-the-sand)

Comment: There are still valid uses, but they aren't very common. Mobile IPv6 for example. The official list is here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-parameters/ipv6-parameters.xhtml#ipv6-parameters-3